# Python - execute a command when an instance of an application is open

Tags: python, subprocess

I have an application on Windows that can only handle a limited number of windows open using it simultaneously (think TextEdit opening several different text files at once). I'd like a python script to monitor the number open simultaneously, and when a user closes one, a new one can open.

I'm new but Subprocess.Popen.wait() seems to only monitor if the entire application is open or closed, not just 1 window (at least for TextEdit, my debugging trial application).

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For something like this on Windows I would use AutoHotKey or AutoIt.

Answer (score 0):

You can check how many instances are open using the cross-platform [`psutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil/5.1.3).

Example:

```
import psutil 

# assuming name of program is `TextEdit.exe`
instances_open = sum(1 for proc in psutil.process_iter() if proc.name() == 'TextEdit.exe')
```